# Show ul on button click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, html-lists

I have a button and a ul under it, the ul is set to display none, what i want to do is when i click on the button the ul appears with white background and i want the button to take the same styling as the ul, and i want the ul's width to be the same as the button's width, how can i do that?
Here is my code:

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $("ul").show();
    
});
```

```css
ul{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button> Hello </button>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You means the button should be with bullets and underline like the ul tag?

Answer (score 0):

> i want the button to take the same styling as the ul

Apply CSS styles to the button. Right now, the only difference appears to be the `font-family`.

> i want the ul's width to be the same as the button's width

Set the button's `width` to be the same as the unordered list using CSS.

The unordered list is shifted to the right because there is left padding. Reduce `padding-left` to reduce how far the items are shifted. The `width` and `padding-left` should add up to the button's `width`.

I have added some CSS for you. Feel free to play around with it more.

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $("ul").show();
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: none;
  width: 85px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

button {
  font-family: serif;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hello</button>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `css()` instead of `show()`.

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $("ul").css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
ul{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button> Hello </button>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```